# How to migrate django template tags completions from vim to lua?

Tags: lua, django-templates, neovim

I recently started to use neovim as my new editor and apparently configurations for django templates tags completion seems to be to hard for me. And I did all king a research but couldn't find a place where these variable or completions were converted from vim to lua.

here they are.

```
  let b:surround_{char2nr("v")} = "{{ \r }}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("{")} = "{{ \r }}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("%")} = "{% \r %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("b")} = "{% block \1block name: \1 %}\r{% endblock \1\1 %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("i")} = "{% if \1condition: \1 %}\r{% endif %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("w")} = "{% with \1with: \1 %}\r{% endwith %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("f")} = "{% for \1for loop: \1 %}\r{% endfor %}"
let b:surround_{char2nr("c")} = "{% comment %}\r{% endcomment %}"
```

I really have no idea how to convert this to lua. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a assignment to buffer options since you are using `b:..`.

Assuming this is a vim plugin called [vim-surround](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697).
If it isn't calling a lua function but just parses the variables you could try assigning it to buffers.

```
vim.b.surround_{char2nr("v")} = "{{ \r }}"
```

If it's a function call, you could try a wrapper. I haven't tested this code since I don't use surround but look at `:h vim.cmd` for tips, it wraps `:h vim.api.nvim_exec`

```lua
local function surround_(a_char, a_tag)
  char_nr = char2nr(a_char)
  cmd = string.format('let b:surround_{ "%s" } = %s', char_nr, a_tag)
  vim.cmd([[ cmd ]])
end

surround_('v', '"{{ \r }}"')
```

Another option might be looking at `:h nvim_buf_set_option`

You might want to consider using the lua variant https://github.com/kylechui/nvim-surround of this plugin, I haven't used this or the vim variant so not sure how much they differs from eachother.

Or just leave this as a vim file, it's just a few mappings.

Vi exchange or neovim forums could help you more.